# react material-ui upload button look weird

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I followed [this MUI document](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/#upload-button)

however, the results look different. The  UI appeared with the button UI.
This should show only the button UI, no  UI.

[image]

I know i can handle this problem by add sx={{diplay:'none'}} propery, and It is work!

**I'm just wondering if there is a mistake I made or if anyone is experiencing this problem.**

below is my code

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Button, Box, Stack, Input, Typography, IconButton } from '@mui/material'
import { PhotoCamera, Delete, Send, Alarm, AddShoppingCart } from '@mui/icons-material'

function PlainButton() {

  return (
    <Stack spacing={3}>
        <Box>
            <Typography sx={{marginTop:1, marginLeft:1}}>Upload Button</Typography>
            <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
                <Input accept="image/*" id="contained-button-file" multiple type="file"/>
                <Button variant="contained" component="span">
                    Upload
                </Button>
            </label>
            <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
                <Input accept="image/*" id="icon-button-file" type="file" sx=/>
                <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span">
                    <PhotoCamera />
                </IconButton>
            </label>
         </Box>
    </Stack>
  )
}

export default PlainButton
```

this is my version info

react version : 18.2.0
@emotion/react: 11.9.3
@emotion/styled: 11.9.3
@mui/icons-material: 5.8.4
@mui/material: 5.8.4

the browser is chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MUI documentation they are also using `display: none` as you can see here:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import PhotoCamera from '@mui/icons-material/PhotoCamera';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';

const Input = styled('input')({
  display: 'none',
});

export default function UploadButtons() {
  return (
    <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center" spacing={2}>
      <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
        <Input accept="image/*" id="contained-button-file" multiple type="file" />
        <Button variant="contained" component="span">
          Upload
        </Button>
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="icon-button-file">
        <Input accept="image/*" id="icon-button-file" type="file" />
        <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span">
          <PhotoCamera />
        </IconButton>
      </label>
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

Comment: oops...I I didn't exapnd the code thank you